# myOpenID is down, who do I ask to recover my account?

Tags: support, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

myOpenID is down so I can't log in.

This account I logged into using google.

Who do I ask to merge this account with my [real account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/168638/trideceth12)?

(I'm assuming I can then ignore myOpenID and log in with google everywhere across the SE network??)